# Snapshot IBM Cloud Object Storage

Tags: amazon-s3, openshift, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

i am trying to figure out if it is possible, also with the help of other softwares (like minio, portworx, veeam etc) to take a snapshot (and eventually restore it later) of the content stored on an IBM Cloud Object Storage instance used as persistence layer for an openshfit cluster through its S3 compatible api endpoints.

Comment: Could you please write a example what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i found this on the official IBM Cloud documentation that achieves somehow what i answered here: basically it explains how to synch tow backets beetwen them, also in different regions, so to have both data and backups on an S3 sotrage

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-region-copy

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this link and see if it provides what you are looking for.
Thanks.  https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-object_storage#cos_backup_restore

Comment: Hi, i think this guide demonstrates how to save backup data on COS and not backing up the data on the COS itself.